# React Query CacheTime ignored in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am trying to prefetch some data on the home screen to display on a different screen (search screen) when the user goes there. I'm trying to set the `cacheTime` to be 24 hours, so it will basically only fetch it once per day. From what I understand, Tanstack Query will garbage collect any query that hasn't been hit by a "useQuery" after 5 minutes by default. But what happens is, when I first land on the home screen, prefetch happens and the results are there immediately when I go to the search page. But if i go back to the home screen and let it sit idle for 5 minutes and go back to search, I get a loading screen and have verified it's re-running the query.

So here's what I've got:

```js
// called on the home screen
export default async function prefetchMostFrequentResults(bar) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ["foo", bar],
    queryFn: async () => {
      // irrelevant implementation detail
    },
    staleTime: 43200000, // 12 hours
    cacheTime: 86400000, // 24 hours
  });
}
```

and on my search screen:

```js
export default function useMostFrequentResults(bar) {
  return {
    ...useQuery({
      queryKey: ["foo", bar],
      queryFn: async () => {...}
      staleTime: 43200000, // 12 hours
      cacheTime: 86400000, // 24 hours
      refetchOnMount: false,
    }),
  };
}
```

I've verified that the dependent key `bar` is not changing during this time, and nothing is calling `invalidateQueries` while idling on the home screen.

I know the idling for 5 minutes sounds contrived, but in essence what happens is the results are prefetched once out of a cold boot, and then every time I background the app and come back hours later, I'm always gonna get that first loading screen.

Could this be some niche bug/edge case with how react query interacts with react native?